# Spliting Array by (.,!,?)

Tags: c

I have a array contains different sentences each of them end with (.) or (!) or(?) like a normal sentences ı wanna split them by these parameters.

```
text1 = strtok(File1.text,"."); 
printf("%s ",text1);
```

as you can see ı just used regular strtok but what happens is it just deletes (.) like if text is "Hello. What are you doing ?" it becomes "HelloWhat are you doing?" i didnt understand why this happens.

Comment: Have you tried to read about `strtok` and how to correctly use it? It is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: You might also want to read about `strcspn`

Comment: Hint: why do you think the delimiter parameter to `strtok` is a string and not a `char`?